# How to get the number in the field in hive?

Tags: sql, hive

An example of this field is "/products/106017388" in the table.

What SQL query shall I write to get the number 106017388 from the field.

Many thanks.

Comment: try with SUBSTR function!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try hive function `regexp_extract`

Something like

```
select regexp_extract(field_name, "([0-9]+)$", 1) from table_name;
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/8A_uKsPDHUCk7V6e) for the description about the regex `([0-9]+)$`

[Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions)

Answer (score 1):

You may use the split command in hive to extract the required value.Like below;

```
select * from test_stackoverflow;
1     /products/106017388
2     /products1/06017388
Time taken: 0.66 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)


  select split(value,'[/]')[2] from test_stackoverflow;
  OK
  106017388
  06017388
  Time taken: 0.105 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
SUBSTR('/products/106017388',11)
```

to get only the integer part..

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".